# Windows Server 2003 GPO for Windows Updates not working with Windows 7 clients

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, group-policy, windows-update

I have a Windows Server 2003 machine which is the server for a small network of Windows 7 Professional machines.

I have set the `Windows Update` settings in group policy to download updates only and ask user whether to install, and to download only on Saturday at 14h. This setting has propagated to the client Windows 7 machines.

The problem is that Windows seems to have started to ignore this setting and all machines are downloading and installing updates continuously. I just had one machine download 72 updates and reboot, only for some of the updates to fail. When it restarted it began downloading 700GB of new updates.

Is there some hidden setting somewhere I have forgotten to set? These continuous updates are disrupting my business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at using [Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/default.aspx) to manage the updates in your environment.